# Keys.ENTER and Keys.RETURN do not properly submit an <input> in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to test an input field by adding a "todo" and then pressing enter, as there is no submit button, but I keep getting an "Unable to find containing form error"

Java:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://www.xxxxx.com");

//add a todo
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.name("todo"));
input.sendKeys("Get some groceries");  

//this outputs Get some groceries  
System.out.println("Text: "+ input.getAttribute("value")); 

input.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);             //exception here
```

I've also tried `input.submit()`, `input.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)`, and also combining them `input.sendKeys("Get some groceries", Keys.RETURN)` but to no avail - they all give the same error.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Todo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="build.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="content">
      <h1>Todo</h1>
      <p><input type="text" name="todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?"/></p>
      <div id="links">
        <a href="/">all</a>
        <a href="/complete">complete</a>
        <a href="/incomplete">incomplete</a>
      </div>
      <ul id="todos"></ul>
    </section>
    <script src="build.js"></script>
    <script>
      require('./client/boot')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed `WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();` to `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` and now it works. Took 2 hours to figure this out and really don't know why this is a solution.

Comment: Maybe HtmlUnit doesn't understand JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is no form in the html shared and we wont be able to submit without the elements inside the form. Its just a text field where you enter the value and there will be no effect of submitting or pressing enter key.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the javascript behind it, but it listens for the enter key on the input. I can't accept my answer yet, but it solved the problem.